# How to close a dialog native element on backdrop click

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I'm using an HTML dialog element, more info in the [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog#creating_a_modal_dialog), and I would like to close it when the user clicks on the backdrop that is created.

Is there any official solution for this? The documentation says:

> When the modal dialog is displayed, it appears above any other dialogs that might be present. Everything outside the modal dialog is inert and interactions outside the dialog are blocked. Notice that when the dialog is open, with the exception of the dialog itself, interaction with the document is not possible; the "Show the dialog" button is mostly obfuscated by the almost opaque backdrop of the dialog and is inert.

I'm also concerned about accessibility. Could I just detect the user clicking on the backdrop and if so, call the `close()` function? Are there any aspects to keep in mind about screen reader users for example?

Thanks in advance